How do I get the bytes that I send to the server using Requests?
I need to get the bytes that I will send to the server via the Request module. I need to get the bytes because I want to send them separately via the Socket module to a special server. How can I do this?
Sample code:
import requests

x = requests.get('http://example.com')

# Here I want to get the bytes of the request.


You'll need to implement the HTTP protocol yourself see this documentation

i think that you can try with the PreparedRequest class, but i've never used it myself

related: Python requests view before sending

@SIGHUP FYI, see my answer.

You can override the send() method of the HTTPConnection like the following example.
import requests
import urllib3

class DummyConnection(urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data = []
    def send(self, data):
        self.data.append(data)

def get_request_bytes(session, req):
    req = req.prepare()
    pool = session.get_adapter(req.url).get_connection(req.url)
    conn = DummyConnection(pool.host, pool.port)
    conn.request(req.method, req.url, headers=req.headers)
    return b''.join(conn.data)

session= requests.Session()
req = requests.Request('GET',
    url='http://a.b.c',
    headers={'a': 'b'},
)
print(get_request_bytes(session, req))

